# Ошибка [Error] expected primary-expression before '}' token

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int amountOfWatermelons;
    int maxWeight = 0;
    int minWeight = 0;
    cin >> amountOfWatermelons;
    vector <int> watermelons;
    for (int i = 0; i < amountOfWatermelons; ++i) }
        int weight;
        cin >> weight;
        watermelons.push_back(weight);
    }
    for (int j = 1; j < amountOfWatermelons - 1; ++j) {
        if (watermelons[j] > watermelons[j - 1]) {
            maxWeight = watermelons[j];
        }
        else if (watermelons[j] < watermelons[j - 1]) {
            minWeight = watermelons[j];
        }
    }
    cout << minWeight << " " << maxWeight;
    return 0;
}
```

При компиляции выводит 10 48 [Error] expected primary-expression before '}' token
Уже полчаса бьюсь, что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ошибка здесь

```
for (int i = 0; i < amountOfWatermelons; ++i) }
```

последняя скобка не в ту сторону.

P.S. Инициализировать вот так `int minWeight = 0;` в данном случае плохо - так как если введете числа по возрастанию, то минимум будет всегда ноль, что вряд ли ожидается. Правильно минимум и максимум инициализировать элементом массива, например самым первым. С максимумом такая же история. Или там ищется не максимум/минимум (так как оно написано неправильно).

Comment: Спасибо, так невнимательно ошибся.. Минимальное значение я уже исправил в лучшую сторону.